# Dual-NIC Ubuntu Netplan configuration for webapp via DMZ and internet via LAN

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, router, routing

I have a Dual homed Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Server that has one NIC in DMZ and the other in LAN. I've been wrestling with the netplan configuration and my searching has found many mixed recommendations on how to accomplish my desired configuration due to the recent changes in gateway configurations and routes. I've read the netplan documentation: https://netplan.readthedocs.io/en/latest/netplan-tutorial/

Currently I have the following settings:

```
ip r

default via 192.168.2.2 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 onlink 

172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown 

172.18.0.0/16 dev br-e9fa8283d45d proto kernel scope link src 172.18.0.1 

192.168.2.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.39 

192.168.14.0/24 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.14.2
```

netplan:

This is the network config written by 'subiquity'

```
    network:
    
      ethernets:
    
        # LAN NIC #
    
        eth0:
    
          addresses:
    
          - 192.168.2.39/24
    
          dhcp4: no
    
          nameservers:
    
            addresses:
    
            - 192.168.2.33
    
            - 192.168.2.99
    
          routes:
    
          - to: default
    
            via: 192.168.2.2
    
            metric: 100
    
            on-link: true
    
        # DMZ NIC #
    
        eth1:
    
          addresses:
    
          - 192.168.14.2/24
    
          dhcp4: no
    
          routes:
    
          - to: 0.0.0.0/0
    
            via: 192.168.14.1
    
            metric: 100
    
            on-link: true
    
            table: 199 #DMZ routing table
    
          routing-policy:
    
          - from: 192.168.14.2
    
            table: 199 #DMZ routing table
    
      version: 2
```

What I'm trying to accomplish:

**1. Allow internet access and Local Networking to go out via LAN connection.**

**2. Allow inbound traffic from our NATed Public IP to the DMZ Interface: 192.168.14.2 to reach our web application and be returned on the originating NIC (DMZ).**

Currently with this configuration I can access the internet, but my web application times out. I've done packet tracing to determine that the flag [S] traffic is making it into the Ubuntu server, but no replies are heading back out.

What I'm finding is if I replace the default route -  default via 192.168.2.2 dev eth0 proto static metric 100 onlink with default via 192.168.14.1 dev eth1 proto static metric 100 onlink then my web application works correctly and I see the return traffic, but then my server has no internet access as I need that traffic (updates, etc) to go out the LAN interface.

Please provide some direction on what netplan configration I need to have to allow the dual-NIC to work and persist on reboot.

Thank you in advance for any help.